# How to call a function declared in App.js

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I have a react native project that uses react-navigation. I have these two screens that are part of a stack navigator. I want to call all API related functions in App.js or the stack navigator rather than directly on a screen. I would also like to use `data` in the two screens. How can I do this?

**App.js**

```
import fetchData from './Data';
export default function App() {

     const [data, setData] = useState([]);
     
     useEffect(() => {
         const fetchAPI = async () => {
             setData1WeekCases(await fetchData());
         };

         fetchAPI();
     }, [setData1WeekCases]);

}
```

**Data.tsx**

```
export const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { countries },
    } = await axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");

    return countries.map((country) => country.name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**StackNavigator.tsx**

```
const AppStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <AppStack.Navigator>
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Home",
        }}
      />

      <AppStack.Screen
        name="DataScreen"
        component={DataScreen}
        options={{
          headerBackTitle: "Summary",
          title: "Data",
        }}
      />
    <AppStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try making a variable outside of your component, setting it to the function you want to export, then exporting the outside variable

Comment: Save the data in useState
Pass the data to screen as params

Comment: Maybe you can use a custom context https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#custom-context

Answer (score 0):

First of all to access data globally like in your case between screens, you have to use state management tool like  [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can find many tutorials for this on youtube if you can't figure it out using the docs.

Secondly if you want to do all the fetching in a separate file then you can create an axios instance in a separate file like this :

```
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
const axiosClient = axios.create();

axiosClient.defaults.baseURL = "API_URL";
axiosClient.defaults.headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  Accept: "application/json",
};

//All request will wait 2 seconds before timeout
axiosClient.defaults.timeout = 2000;

axiosClient.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export default axiosClient;
axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authtoken = JSON.parse(token); 
    }
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    return console.log(error);
  },
);
export function getRequest(URL) {
  return axiosClient
    .get(URL)
    .then((response) => response)
    .catch((err) => err);
}

export function postRequest(URL, payload) {
  //! step for x-www-form-urlencoded data
  const params = new URLSearchParams(payload);
  return axiosClient.post(URL, params).then((response) => response);
}

export function patchRequest(URL, payload) {
  return axiosClient.patch(URL, payload).then((response) => response);
}

export function deleteRequest(URL) {
  return axiosClient.delete(URL).then((response) => response);
}
```

Fetch data from the api then change the state using redux to get the response in every screen.